# Entity Framework 7 Include() Order

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

In MVC6/EF7, should there be a difference in an order I use Include() to include navigation properties into a query?

This query works

```
var vt = await db.VehicleTypes
            .Include(t => t.Photos)
            .Include(t => t.VehicleModels)
            .ThenInclude(m => m.Units)
            .Include(t => t.Rates)
            .ThenInclude(r => r.DailyPrice.Currency)
            .ToListAsync()
```

But this query throws an exception at ToListAsync()

```
var vt = await db.VehicleTypes
            .Include(t => t.Photos)
            .Include(t => t.Rates)
            .ThenInclude(r => r.DailyPrice.Currency)
            .Include(t => t.VehicleModels)
            .ThenInclude(m => m.Units)
            .ToListAsync()
```

The error is

```
ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
```

Parameter name: index

I understand it's Beta, there may be bugs. In this case - is it a bug or a designed behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug; the order shouldn't matter. Would you mind [creating an issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/new)?